# A and B have negative correlation, so -A and -B have positive?

Tags: probability, correlation

If A and B have negative correlation, would I be correct to assume -A and -B have positive correlation?

eg taking an example of -ve correlation: A student who has many absences has a decrease in grades.

so taking -A and -B: A student who is always present has an increase in grades - which is positive correlation.

So is my assumption in the 1st line true?

Comment: No - if $A$ and $B$ are negatively correlated then $A$ and $-B$ are positively correlated and so $-A$ and $-B$ are negatively correlated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are negatively correlated, increasing $A$ decreases $B$.

But since increasing $A$ is equivalent to decreasing $-A$ and decreasing $B$ is equivalent to increasing $-B$, the previous statement is equivalent to “Decreasing $-A$ increases $-B$”, which means $-A$ and $-B$ are also negatively correlated.